# Appending object to list modifies object

Tags: python, oop

When I run this code:

```
class Node:
    children = []
    num_children = 0
    isleaf = True
    def __init__(self,name):
        print("constructor called for " + name)
        self.name = str(name)



    def add_child(self,child_node):
        print("adding child called "+child_node.name+ " to "+ self.name)
        print("I ("+self.name+ ") have " + str(len(self.children)) + " children")
        print("checking: " + child_node.name + " reports " + str(len(child_node.children)) + " children")
        #cc = copy.deepcopy(child_node)
        self.children.append(child_node)
        #self.children.append(1)
        #self.children[0] = child_node
        print("checking again: " + child_node.name + " reports " + str(len(child_node.children)) + " children")
        self.isleaf = False
        self.num_children = self.num_children +1
        print("I ("+self.name+ ") now have " + str(len(child_node.children)) + " children")



root = Node("a")


testn = Node("b")

root.add_child(testn)


print(root.children[0].name)
```

I get this output:

```
constructor called for a
constructor called for b
adding child called b to a
I (a) have 0 children
checking: b reports 0 children
checking again: b reports 1 children
I (a) now have 1 children
b
```

why does the line of code:

```
self.children.append(child_node)
```

add a child to the child (`B`) as well as the parent (`A`)?

I would expect it to only add a child to the parent (`A`)

Comment: Do you want `children` to be a class variable?

Comment: yes children should be a member of node. I'm trying and failing to implement a tree

Comment: If you want `children` to be an instance variable, make it one. See my answer below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is not a duplicate as the error was caused by a typo. Why did you downvote it?

Comment: Apparently you had more than one problem. The issue with data being shared amongst instances, the original question you asked, is definitely the duplicate I closed this against, as the answers that were posted tell you. If there's another issue, that should be a separate question, don't edit the question with your next problem. If the new problem is just a typo, don't ask it at all; they are not useful to others. And please don't edit answers into the question, either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you don't know the nature/cause of the error then its impossible to know if another question contains the answer. Hence down voting serves no useful purpose

Comment: But we do know the cause of the error. As reported, as you wrote the question, data was being shared unexpectedly because you have a mutable class attribute when you needed an instance attribute. If that's not actually the problem you're trying to solve that's on you, as the author of the question; the rest of us can only go on what you write. If you have another problem subsequent to solving the first one, that should be the subject of a separate inquiry (unless, again, it's just a typo).

Answer (score 0):

Move `children = []` into `__init__` to make it an *instance* member. Right now it is a *class* member:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.children = []
    self.num_children = 0
    self.isleaf = True
```

Comment: that results in b not having any children :(

Comment: @RNs_Ghost which is the correct behaviour, no? Also, why do you have an attribute that duplicates `len(self.children)`?

Comment: sorry i mean that results in a not having any children. That duplicate exists because I have been trying lots of different things to debug it

Answer (score 0):

That's because you defined children as a *class variable* and not as an *instance variable*. Meaning that `children` doesn't really belong to `root` or `testn` but rather to the class `Node` itself.

To fix it just replace `children = []` by `self.children = []` inside the `__init__`.

Comment: This results in (a) not having any children